# Talking of which or speaking of which?

Tags: word-choice

I'm reading a book that was a translation to English from an original German text written only a few years ago.  The translation has the phrase "talking of which", in the sense of "Talking of which, XYZ is also true".  As a native English speaker, I have never once said "talking of which" and instead say it as "speaking of which".  Is "talking of which" a bad translation, or is that phrasing used in other contexts?

Comment: There's the problem of translating into not-your-mother tongue.

Comment: Have you checked in a dictionary, eg [Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/talking-of)? Compared [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=talking+of+which%2Cspeaking+of+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctalking%20of%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeaking%20of%20which%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctalking%20of%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspeaking%20of%20which%3B%2Cc0)? These indicate that 'talking of which' is used, acceptable, but a lot less commonly used than 'speaking of which'.

Comment: There's no doubt ***talking of which*** is very rare compared to ***speaking of which*** as an aid to discursive segueing into a closely-related subject. And until now I always thought it was invariably ***Speak of the Devil!*** to announce that someone being discussed "behind their back" has just joined a conversation. But apparently in *British* (not American) English, [***Talk of the Devil***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speak+of+the+Devil%2Ctalk+of+the+Devil&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=10) is in fact more common today.

Answer (score 1):

*Speaking of which* is common in American English. *Talking of which* is technically okay but sounds odd. ‘Talking’ usually pairs with ‘about’.